# Unable to correctly logout after changed wp-login.php

Tags: php, filters, login, actions

I've followed a guide on internet that suggested how to change the wp-login.php page to something custom by modifing the wp-login.php file itself and by renaming it.

I've copied the wp-login.php original file and I've renamed it to login.php
After this I've used the following code into the functions file to be sure that all is working fine.

I have this first function that will check if the requested url is the correct one that will point to the login.php file

```php
/** Hide default login */
function hide_default_login() {

    //Only proceed for guests
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {

        //Getting current page
        $current_url   = str_replace( '/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
        $hiddenWpAdmin = 'login'; //Change this to your new secret wp-admin url
        $redirectNaTo  = '/';

        //Checking if accessing correct login url
        if ( $current_url == $hiddenWpAdmin ) {
            wp_redirect( '/'.$hiddenWpAdmin.'.php' );
            exit;
        }

        //Only allow requests to wp-login.php coming from correct login url
        $adminToCheck = [
            'wp-admin',
            'wp-login.php'
        ];
        
        if (
            in_array( $current_url, $adminToCheck )
            &&
            $_GET['action'] !== "logout"
        ) {
            wp_redirect( $redirectNaTo );
            exit();
        }
    }
}

add_action('init', 'hide_default_login');
```

Than I have this other function that will apply a filter to be sure that the wp_login_url function will point to the correct URL when used

```php
function custom_login_url( $login_url, $redirect, $force_reauth ){
    $login_url = site_url( 'login.php', 'login' );
    if ( ! empty( $redirect ) ) {
        $login_url = add_query_arg( 'redirect_to', urlencode( $redirect ), $login_url );
    }
    if ( $force_reauth ) {
        $login_url = add_query_arg( 'reauth', '1', $login_url );
    }
    return $login_url;
}
add_filter( 'login_url', 'custom_login_url', 10, 3 );

function logout_custom_redirect(){
    wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
}
add_action('wp_logout', 'logout_custom_redirect');
```

Anyway when I try to logout from wordpress I will get a 404 error because the CMS will try to send me to the wp-login page so I'm unable to logout correctly at the moment.
Is there any issue into the code or a fix I can apply?